# Loop list data in Java Spring Boot with Primefaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, primefaces

Hello so i wanted to make a little projects, but i'm currently don't know the "keyword" to search for it. I wanted to make a job applying site, and how do i list all the job from job table in the so like "bootstrap card" but in Primefaces?
Fyi: The region is from Region table.
I don't know what to search the keyword for it...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces is an open-source user interface (UI) component library, the following components may help you to achieve your goal :

1. NAVBAR: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menubar.xhtml

[image]

2. SIDE MENU: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/slideMenu.xhtml

[image]

3. CARD: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datagrid/basic.xhtml

[image]

**How to use Primefaces**

You just need to [download](https://www.primefaces.org/downloads/) PrimeFaces, add the primefaces-{version}.jar to your classpath and import the namespace to get started.

PrimeFaces namespace is necessary to add PrimeFaces components to your pages.

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

For PrimeFaces Mobile, the namespace would be;

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
```

That’s it

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <h:head>

     </h:head>

     <h:body>

         <p:spinner />

     </h:body>
</html>
```